# How can i count total like in group by book_id and order_id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
book_id  order_id  amount    behav
-------- -------   -------  -------
   a      d1         10       like
   a      d1         10       like
   a      d1         10       unlike
   a      d2         20       unlike
   a      d2         20       unlike
   a      d3         30       like
   b      d4         20       like
   b      d4         20       unlike
   b      d5         30       unlike
```

How would I write a mySQL to do table like this?

```
 book_id     amount        count(behav)==> count behav = like
 --------   -------        -------------
    a         60 d1+d2+d3        3
    b         50 d4+d5           1
```

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, you can just use `sum()` on the boolean expression:

```
select book_id, sum(amount), sum(behav = 'like')
from t
group by book_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate it twice to eliminate amount doubles

```
select book_id, sum(amount) amount, sum(cnt) countLike
from(
    select book_id, max(amount) amount, sum(behav = 'like') cnt
    from t
    group by book_id, order_id
) t
group by book_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
book_id,
sum(amount) as total_sum,
count(case when behav = 'like' then 1 else 0 end) as total_behav_count
from table
group by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in MySQL!!!

```
    SELECT book_id, SUM(amount), COUNT(book_id) FROM `book` WHERE behav="like" group by book_id
```